# "This webpage has a redirect loop" in Chrome but working fine on FF and IE?

Tags: debugging, google-chrome, browser

The page http://www.japanforum.com/forum/japanese-language-help/39454-~tara-past-tense-clause.html is accessible using FireFox / IE / Safar / Opera.

However on Chrone, the page doesn't display:

[image]

Does anyone know what may be the cause of the problem?

Or rather, what is the explanation for this phenomenon?

Comment: I tried it, it worked in firefox but fails in chrome. Just as you said. Interesting!

Comment: Your server is emitting `301 moved permanently` headers for Chrome though - you may need to look into the server side configuration why.

Comment: FYI, I have the exact same problem with GOOGLE DOCS. Really. When you try to change the there of a form (from a spreadsheet), you get that error. It's working fine in Firefox tho.

Comment: @Pekka this is not my website. i happen to stumble on the mystery and was wondering what's it all about

Comment: @Dominic Goulet The Google Docs problem for me was related to having Google Apps domain and multiple sign-in with Chrome. If I am sure to be only signed in to ONE account, I don't get the redirect problem when trying to change Themes in a Form of Google Docs.

Comment: Also happens on http://uva.onlinejudge.org/. It's really annoying.

Comment: I also having the same problem. I have just deleted the browsing history of past hour and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 6):

I appears that you are trying to redirect to the correct SEO-friendly URL, e.g. if I go to `test/39454-foo.html`, it redirects me to `test/39454-~tara-past-tense-clause.html`.

You compare the requested URI to the expected one and redirect if they do not match.

However, there are multiple ways of writing the same URI. Some browsers may send `~` urlencoded and some may not, for example.

So you should *canonicalize* both URIs before comparing them.

Comment: i think you are misunderstanding something.. this is not my website (btw take a look at the question again)

Comment: +1 Apart from using “you” and giving advice, this answer pretty much nails it.

Answer (score 3):

Double-check the redirection settings on your server. Add-on domains should not include "www." when being added. Without this, this will solve the redirection problem.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether all Google's cookies are allowed in your [cookie settings](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?rd=1) (especially see the *Manage Exceptions* window).

Comment: This solved my problem, some of google's cookies were blocked. When I unblocked them, problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

This can sometimes occurs if the URL-mapping of the page has one or more redirect-conditions.
If the software behind tries to redirect to the same URL-mapper (->bad programming).
The result is a loop of mapping und redirecting in the Controller.

Comment: This did not explain why Chrome gets stuck in the loop whereas FireFox and IE are able to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I faced the same issue couple of months ago and as mentioned in [Solution 1 here](https://www.geekdashboard.com/fix-this-webpage-has-a-redirect-loop/), the culprit is the browser cookies.

You can simply clear the cache and cookies of your browser and the problem will be fixed.